# Product of independent Martingales with respect to natural filtration is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

I have found the solution of this problem to the following paper http://alexanderchernyy.com/pmt.pdf , theorem 2.1,  page 4. 
However I am struggling to convince myself about the statement:

$$ E(X_t  Y_t|\mathcal{F}^X_s\vee\mathcal{F}^Y_s)= X_s Y_s $$
 implies $$E(X_t  Y_t|\mathcal{F}^{XY}_s) = X_s Y_s $$

Where does this implication come from?

Comment: There is a detailed proof in that theorem. Which step in that proof you have difficulty with?

Comment: The last row of the proof, so the implication above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use the $\pi - \lambda$ theorem (and not monotone class theorem). Sets of the type $A\cap B$ with $A \in \mathcal F^{X}_s$ and $B \in \mathcal F^{Y}_s$ form a $\pi$ system and the class defined in that reference is a $\lambda$ system containing this $\pi$ system. Hence it contains the sigma algebra generated, which is $\sigma(\mathcal F^{X}_s \cup \mathcal F^{Y}_s)$. Final step where this last sigma algebra is replaced by $\mathcal F^{XY}_s$ is immediate from definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: I really thank you for your answer and will to help me. The $\pi - \lambda$ theorem is exactly what I used for the first part. However I still cannot see why the replacement of the sigma algebra in the last row of the proof is an immediate result of the conditional expectation definition.

Comment: Suppose $E(X|\mathcal G_1)=Y, \mathcal G_0 \subset \mathcal G_1$ and we already know that $Y$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal G_0$. Then $E(X|\mathcal G_0)=Y$. This is immediate from the definition of conditional expectation. In the present case $\mathcal F^{XY}_s $ is contained in the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal F^{X}_s  \cup $\mathcal F^{Y}_s $.

Comment: Yes of course! But the real issue was proving that $\mathcal F^{XY}_s \subset \mathcal F^{X}_s  \cup \mathcal F^{Y}_s$.  However I managed to prove that. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathcal{F}_s^{XY} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_s^X \vee \mathcal{F}_s^Y$ for all $s \geq 0$; this follows from the fact that the product $X_s Y_s$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_s^X \vee \mathcal{F}_s^Y$. Hence, by the tower property of conditional expectation,

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t Y_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s^{XY}) = \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(X_t Y_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s^X \vee \mathcal{F}_s^Y)}_{=X_s Y_s} \mid \mathcal{F}_s^{XY} \bigg] = X_s Y_s.$$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help! That is exactly what I have proved by my own.

Comment: @AlbiToro I see; glad to hear that.